# Swift UI - Embed Video Unavailable

Tags: swift, swiftui, embed

I am still fairly new with using SwiftUI. I am creating my first app and I was trying to embed a youtube video into my app, but I keep running into this problem where the video is automatically unavailable for whatever reason. Here is my code down below. Im not totally sure what I did wrong.

```
struct VideoView: UIViewRepresentable{

let videoID: String

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    return WKWebView()
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    guard let youtubeURL = URL (string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)")
    else {
        return
    }
    uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    uiView.load(URLRequest(url: youtubeURL))
}
```

}

Some Pictures down below:

[The Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16OVh.png)

[Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvch1.png)

[Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa6hR.png)

Comment: It looks like the specific video you're trying to view has embedding turned off. Have you tried other videos?

Comment: No I haven't. I will try another video real quick.

Comment: I went into youtube to allow embed for the video since I created the video. But for whatever reason it wont work still.

Comment: Did you try any *other* videos that allow embedding? That would isolate whether it's an issue with your code or if it's a YouTube issue.

Comment: Yup I just tried out 3 other videos. 2 of them work but the other one had the same issue for whatever reason. It must be something on youtube end. All of them say allow embedding but for whatever reason only 2 of the videos worked.